# Can I use Session in MVC to pass (reference) objects from controller to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, controller

**General goal**: I'm converting the "Client" project from a solution with 4 projects (Client/Domain/Data/Testing) and turning the Client into an MVC. The previous version of the program was as a console-line program. The program simulates 'ordering' food.

The basic user lifecycle: logging in, selecting food options, adding the food options to a cart (an order). I am trying to convert it now into a web app.

**Problem**:

I want to add a food object to an order object. This order object will then be added to a customer object. However, I cannot determine a way to bring the order created upon logging in via an account controller into my food controller, where I create the food / want to add it to the order.

When it was a console line app, it was easier to change the scope, since I could just put the food customization process in a while-loop (i.e. 'while ordering') and declare/initialize the order object outside of the loop. However, now that it's MVC, I can't figure out exactly how to do it otherwise.

**What I've tried:**
I looked into Session / TempData. Given I want the order to last while a user is logged in, I figured Session was the way to go. From what I saw, it seemed like session only can have strings/int32s set to it. Thus, I cannot give my FoodController direct access to the created order. 
I then tried a workaround via having the order stored in a database. I took the primary key of the created order, stored it in a Session object as an int while in the AccountController, and retrieved the key in my FoodController. Then, I tried to find the object via the key by using a `Context.Set<T>().Find(id);` in my repository. Then... I ran into errors with something not converting right in that from Int64 to Int32.

Before I spend even more hours of frustration figuring out why my repo isn't working now, I was trying to determine if there is a better way of going about this.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What makes you think that Session can only have strings and ints?

Comment: @mason I noticed that the intellisense only had the SetString and SetInt32 showing regarding the 'Set' methods. I believe there was also a tutorial (although the link escapes me) that mentioned it as strings/ints. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a Set method? It's as easy as `Session["CurrentOrder"] = currentOrder;` to add it to the session. Later you can do `Order currentOrder = Session["CurrentOrder"] as Order;` to retrieve it.

Comment: Is this MVC5 or MVC Core? Session works very differently in these two.

Comment: @JasperKent This is MVC Core.

Comment: @mason It doesn't seem to recognize it. When I was looking around, it seems to be something to do with the MVC version I'm on...? It seems to only let me access Session via HttpContext.

Comment: In that case, you can only save ints and strings. You can save more complex object by turning them into strings with JSON serialization. But you won't be storing references to the objects, you'll be storing copies.

You can stills store references in the memory-cache, but they won't be automatically associated with a specific session/user.

Comment: @JasperKent Ahh that helps, thanks. I think I found a good walkthrough through it https://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/

Comment: Why don't you think about using `TempData`? I think it was created for such a situation. When you want to pass data  from one request to another (even if the new request is handled by another controller). https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: @Anton TempData is a poor choice for a shopping cart.

Comment: I hadn't worked with Session in ASP.NET Core before (you should tag your question to indicate that's what you're using, as you're currently tagged as though using the old ASP.NET framework). Even if you can only store strings and ints, it's trivial to serialize an object to JSON, see [tutorials like this one](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/store-complex-objects-in-asp-net-core-session/) for Session in ASP.NET Core.